# Inframe Street View issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have the followings issue. (Please refer to the attached images below.)

The issue: As the inframe view moves over the APS viewer, the Street View position inside of inframe view returns to the default position, position.

The issue has been happening under the following work steps.

1. Street View Frame is activated from a button on the menu.

2. A Street View Frame appears as an Inframe, showing the view from the first default position, position A.

3. Within the Inframe Viewer, move to the other position, Position B. View from position B is projected.

4. Move the Inframe View over the APS Viewer.

5. As the inframe view moves, the Street View position returns from position B to the default position, position A.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeIpi.png)      [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxnoX.png)

Question: Is there a way to move the Inframe View without bringing the position back to the default position?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are embedding a 3rd party library (Matterport Street View?) into the APS viewer using an `<iframe>` and a custom UI panel, and when you move the custom panel around, the state of the Street View inside the `<iframe>` somehow resets?

I'm not aware of any Matterport extension available for our viewer so I'm assuming this is a 3rd party extension or one developed by you directly? Either way, you will need to reach out to the author of this extension for support.

Comment: Hi Petr, 

As you mentioned, the 3rd party library (Matterport Street View) is enbedded onto the APS viewer. 
Also, the your understanding about the issue is correct. 

We will contact the Matterport supoort. 


Thank you for your answer.